# Dynamically import React component from external URL and use parent React environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a Main UI into which I want to load a Sub UI in the form of a React Component, which is then integrated through a `React.Suspense` JSX Tag. The Main and the Sub UI will both be separately bundled with Webpack. The Sub UI is bundled as a `Webpack 5 Module Library`.

Now, the dynamic loading of the component from an URL seems to be no problem. I can use

```js
var path = "<< some URL to a JS-File in a CDN >>";
var SubUiComponent = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ path));
```

But because the component that I want to import is bundled with Webpack, another React instance is being used. I have already tried to use Webpack Externals, but there seems to be no way that it can be used in combination with dynamic imports.

When I'm not defining externals, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips
>    about how to debug and fix this problem.

With externals defined in `webpack.config.js`, I get the expected error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

So, is there a way of bundling a React component "kind of" as a library and then import it into another React Environment and use it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two of your different local react projects, you want to link/refer/import one from another? If this is what you're trying to do then yes, it is possible.

**First Approach:**

You need to research on [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link#description)

Note that package-name is taken from package.json, not from the directory name.

`npm link` in a package folder will create a symlink in the global folder `{prefix}/lib/node_modules/<package>` that links to the package where the npm link command was executed.

It will also link any bins in the package to `{prefix}/bin/{name}`. Note that npm link uses the global prefix (see `npm prefix -g` for its value).

In some other location, `npm link package-name` will create a symbolic link from globally-installed package-name to `node_modules/` of the current folder

```
    cd ~/projects/some-dep
    npm link                # Step 1.
    cd ~/projects/my-app
    npm link some-dep       # Step 2.
```

now, from your my-app folder, you can install some-dep

```
    ~/projects/my-app
     npm install some-dep@
```

**Second Approach:**

Bundle and publish your project to npm registry then install, import it into your other project. [Refer this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mytidbit) that I'd published to try out

**Third Approach:**

Webpack ModuleFederation, when you import the project/module, it will look for it in node_modules, if not found then in the federated modules.

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/

Comment: The problem is, the two projects aren't necesseraily local.. the Sub-Ui should be loadable just from an external JS-File, no matter where it's built

Comment: @ChristophPader How about publishing sub-ui to npm registry and install, import into other project? I've updated my answer with all the approaches I know of.

Comment: @ChristophPader did that help with your requirement? pls do accept the answer if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try https://github.com/Paciolan/remote-component

```
const url = "https://remote.../HelloWorld.js";

const HelloWorld = ({ name }) => <RemoteComponent url={url} name={name} />;

const Container = (
  <>
    <HelloWorld name="Remote" />
  </>
);
```

or https://github.com/Paciolan/remote-module-loader

```
import loadRemoteModule from "./lib/loadRemoteModule";

const myModule = loadRemoteModule("https://remote.../my-module.js");

myModule.then(m => {
  const MyComponent = m.default();
  console.log({ MyComponent });
});
```